# Is "this" static? Checking for Static in the constructor

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I need to determine if a member T of class T is a static member, in the constructor.  I expect this will involve checking some attributes of "this", but I haven't been able to determine what to look for.

```
public class Thing
{
    public static readonly List<Thing> ListOfStaticThings = new();
    public static readonly Thing StaticThing1 = new ("StaticThing1");
    public static readonly Thing StaticThing2 = new ("StaticThing2");
    public static readonly Thing StaticThing3 = new ("StaticThing3");
    public Thing NonStaticThing = new("NonStaticThing");
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private Thing(string name) 
    {
        Name = name;
        if(this.IsStatic)  //how to determine if the thing being constructed is static?
        { ListOfStaticThings.Add(this);}
    }

}
```

How do I identify if the `Static` attribute is applied to `this`?

*** UPDATED ***

In this example, both StaticThing and NonStaticThing will be constructed using the private constructor.  However, only the StaticThing should be added to the ListOfStaticThings when constructed. The full implementation will have 20+ static readonly fields of the class type.

I've already verified that the ListOfStaticThings will contain the StaticThing.

The ListOfStaticThings has multiple uses.  This is on the path to [Enumeration Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types), with this list containing all the possible Things (such as account statuses) permitted by the class.  In addition, the ListOfStaticThings can be passed to EFCore.HasData to seed the data in the table.  It can also be used for data validation in unit testing because it contains all the data and is persisted in the model.

However, all those use cases are beyond the scope of this question.  The piece I'm looking for is how to identify if the "this" being constructed is static so I can add it to the ListOfStaticThings.  I want StaticThing1, 2 & 3 to be in the list, but not NonStaticThing.

*** Final Update ***
As pointed out by McAden's answer, this is not necessary because the non-static member of T cannot be added to class T without causing an infinite recursion overflow.  Since only static members of T can be added, there is no need to determine if they are also static in the constructor.

Comment: *"if the thing being constructed is static"* - Not possible. The context--being a static field--is not conveyed to the constructor.

Comment: if it is being constructed, it _always_ is an instance. unless you are considering a [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) - in which case, it is _always_ static, and there is no `this`)

Comment: Can you clarify what "class T" is with respect to the source code you are showing?

Comment: Technically, you can use `if (MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().IsStatic) {...}` to check if current executing method is `static` one.

Comment: To check if type `T` is a `static class`: `if (typeof(T).IsAbstract && typeof(T).IsSealed) { ... };`

Comment: I've updated title (and touched up body of the post) - please confirm that it matches the question you wanted to ask (that `this.IsStatic` looked quite confusing)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  I rolled back the edit.  I already know the constructor is called.  I just need to determine if the thing being called is static or not.

Comment: This is unclear. What is the scenario where you're writing the constructor for a class but don't know if it's static or not?

Comment: @ScottHannen  The class T is not static, but there are members of T within the class that are static.

I've added a bit more to the code sample to see if that helps clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Same thing. If T has a member, it's always going to be either static or non-static. This is something known. How can it be unknown. Another way of looking at it - if it's uncertain whether the member is static or not, how is it certain that the member exists?

Comment: @WesH note that you explicitly said that you are not interested in knowing where value will be assigned, but interested in some mysterious "the Static attribute is applied to this" *before* it is assigned to a field. Stay consistent :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: Within the constructor you can't know, if this instance will be assigned to a static field, because assignment happens after construction.

Comment: What if some other class sets a non-static field like `Thing MyThing = Thing.StaticThing1`? Would you consider that to be "static" because `StaticThing1` was static, or non-static because the other class references it in a non-static field?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior In your exaple, MyThing would not be considered static.  It would also be used outside the Thing class.  I can't imagine why a dev would need to create a instance of a static value rather than just using the static value, but I guess they can if they need to.

Comment: @WesH Well it's the same Thing as the one that's static.  This points to your inherent misunderstanding here.  An instance isn't a "static" or "instance" instance.  It's not a sensible property to apply to an instance of a class.  A particular *variable* is static or non-static, but the variable is different from the object the variable references.

Comment: This whole question makes no sense at all. An instance is an instance is an instance. There is nothing static about it. The field may be static or instance, but that's nothing got to do with the actual object. To create your `List` you can just move it a few lines later and do `public static readonly List<Thing> ListOfStaticThings = new List<Thing>{StaticThing1, StaticThing2, StaticThing3};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**:

In OP's very specific preferred approach there's no point. The `public Thing NonStaticThing = new("NonStaticThing");` will result in a `StackOverflowException` as each child will try to create another child infinitely.

In general, however, my advice to anybody trying to do something "statically" and otherwise "not" would be to use a static constructor for static things.

**Original Answer based upon un-edited question**:

Order of operations - The static field will be assigned before anything else outside that class can call the constructor on that class and the constructor for setting that static readonly field will be called before the static field is actually assigned. Simply check to see if the static field is null in your constructor.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var test = new Thing();
    Console.WriteLine(test.IsStaticInstance); // False
    Console.WriteLine(Thing.Instance.IsStaticInstance); // True
}

public class Thing
{
    public static readonly Thing Instance = new Thing();
    public Thing()
    {
        IsStaticInstance = Instance == null;
    }
    public bool IsStaticInstance { get; }
}
```

Comment: The constructor in my example is Private.  It is only used to construct the Thing members within the class.

I will have multiple Thing members in the class, but I want the constructor to behave differently for the static members.

Comment: Note that if one constructs another instance of `Thing` inside such constructor it will be entertaining(tm) :)

Comment: Oh, I missed that. That won't ever work regardless of whether you can figure out it's static or not - that's a classic `StackOverflow` - each `Thing` will create another `Thing` infinitely. Unless you only want the static one to have its `Thing` references populated? In which case, I'd recommend rethinking your class design as it violates good architecture.

Comment: @McAden I don't think it would SO. OP is planning to do something special for static fields - i.e. you have `static Node Root` and it will have Left and Right nodes. So they would construct values for those Left/Right non-static properties inside "special code when detected that the Static attribute is applied to this"

Comment: @McAden Interesting observation.  Part of my purpose in this question is to ensure that non-static members of T would not get added to the List<T>.  This is to ensure additional members cannot be used when incorrectly declared.  However, your statement points out that a instance of T containing an instance of T would potentially causing an infinite recursion and would never finish the constructor, but would instead hang the code.  If I'm correct in that assumption, the answer becomes that there is no need because it is impossible to add the non-static member of T to the list within class T.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going about it the wrong way - all static members should be initialized either in the property itself or in a static constructor, so I would do it this way:

```
public class Thing
{
    public static readonly List<Thing> ListOfStaticThings;
    public static readonly Thing StaticThing1 = new Thing("StaticThing1");
    public static readonly Thing StaticThing2 = new Thing("StaticThing2");
    public static readonly Thing StaticThing3 = new Thing("StaticThing3");
    // public Thing NonStaticThing = new("NonStaticThing");
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private Thing(string name) 
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    static Thing()
    { 
        ListOfStaticThings = new List<Thing> {
            StaticThing1, 
            StaticThing2, 
            StaticThing3
        };
    }

}
```

Now the instance constructor doesn't *need* to know if it's a "static" instance or not.

However, to be safe (meaning not rely on the order of initializers), I would also crate the static instances in the static constructor:

```
public class Thing
{
    public static readonly List<Thing> ListOfStaticThings;
    public static readonly Thing StaticThing1;
    public static readonly Thing StaticThing2;
    public static readonly Thing StaticThing3;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private Thing(string name) 
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    static Thing()
    { 
        ListOfStaticThings = new List<Thing> {
            StaticThing1 = new Thing("StaticThing1"), 
            StaticThing2 = new Thing("StaticThing2"), 
            StaticThing3 = new Thing("StaticThing3")
        };
    }

}
```

Now, if you need to know if it's "static" for some *other* reason, then I would create another private constructor that takes a static flag:

```
private Thing(string name, bool isStatic=False) : this(name) 
{
    if (isStatic) {
        // Do different stuff for a "static" instance
    }
}
```

but I would not put logic there to "add itself" to a static list - that can be accomplished more cleanly another way.

---

> how [do I] prevent non-static members being added to the list

If you want to make the list immutable, then you could either expose it as an immutable type or interface like 'IEnumerable', or you could just
generate the list on the fly with a static property getter:

```
public static IEnumerable<Thing> ListOfStaticThings {
    get {
        return new List<Thing> {
            StaticThing1, 
            StaticThing2, 
            StaticThing3
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Abandoned my answer, static constructor is the way to go IMO. Though you've still got the OP's original code with `public Thing NonStaticThing = new("NonStaticThing");` so there'll be a `StackOverflow` as each Thing infinitely creates a child thing

Comment: I've considered this, but the concern I have is that static members have to be explicitly added to the list.  By adding it in the constructor, they are included in the list without additional code.

Comment: @McAden Please write that up as an answer and I'll accept it.  I overlooked the infinite recursion and that answers the inverse of my question, how to prevent non-static members being added to the list... they can't because the code will overflow if tried.

Comment: un-abandoned my answer an edited it, though I kept the original answer and all the comment history.

Comment: Required read https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/BeforeFieldInit... probably that link (and written acknowledge that every person looking at the code read and understood that) should be added to the code if you copy it from this answer to your own project. (I'd avoid adding dependency on order between static field initializers and static constructors for this reason :) )

Comment: @McAden Good catch-  I did not see that originally, but I think it's orthogonal to the problem.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov In reality I would also create the static instances in the static constructor for the same reason - to be explicit that they need to be created first. I'll add that.

Comment: "the concern I have is that static members have to be explicitly added to the list." Why is that a concern? You _could_ add it to the list in the constructor and just pass in `true` for `isStatic` (`StaticThing1 = new Thing("StaticThing1", true)`. The bottom line is that there's no way to know in an instance constructor that the instance is being assigned to a static property.